# Visiting/using a decommissioned ex-church

Tags: halacha, christianity, real-estate

[Visiting sites previously used for idol worship](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43567/visiting-sites-previously-used-for-idol-worship) asks about visiting a historical site previously used for idolatry, and talks about ruins and the possibility of extant religious symbols.  My question is about a building that was previously a church (but otherwise nothing special) and that was decommissioned in an orderly fashion and sold.

What issues, if any, arise from using such a building?  Does it matter what the new purpose is?  For example, an ex-church has been converted into a concert hall -- can Jews enter?  Or a synagogue is looking for a building -- can they use an ex-church?  Does it matter what architectural features remain (bell tower, [cross on the roof](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37928/472), etc)?

Are ex-churches wholly off-limits, or does it depend?  If the latter, on what does it depend?

(Locally there is an ex-church that is now a (non-kosher) brewery and restaurant, and it got me wondering if Jews could do that if they wanted to.)

Comment: FWIW [Kehillas Beis Yisrael in East Denver](https://www.baisyisroel.com) used to be a church. I can see about asking the Rav about the relevant halachos, B”N.

Comment: Anecdotally FWIW, there are a number of synagogues in former church buildings.

Comment: @msh210 thanks -- it seemed possible but I didn't know of any.  (I know of a few that went the other direction.)

Comment: I know that when they turned a church into a shul in my community 
(in America) they made changes to the building.  I don't know how extensive they where or if they were halachicly necessary.