# Is a Jew allowed to collect royalties on a song that glorifies Jesus?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, business

You may not, offhand recognize the name [Norman Greenbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Greenbaum) until you realize that he composed the One-Hit wonder song "Spirit in the Sky" first released in 1969, and played often on radio and other media.

> "Spirit in the Sky" contains lyrics about the afterlife, making
>   several references to Jesus, although Greenbaum is Jewish. (Wikipedia)

Is Greenbaum or any Jew allowed to compose as well as make money on the sales of songs that contain reference to other gods?

Comment: tangentially related discussions related to physical things (is there a kal vachomer to songs?) http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/07/chess-pieces/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28983/should-the-christian-cross-be-seen-as-an-idol and some discussion of music http://www.jewishvaluesonline.org/question.php?id=1199&cprg=%2Fsearch.php%3Fcatid%3D35