# Is it okay for me to wear a Star of David and cross necklace?

Tags: christianity, star-of-david

I’m an ethnic Jew and through Jewish Law I am a Jew (my mother was raised Catholic, but her mother was Jewish and the rest of that side of family is Jewish). I was raised Christian and am extremely devoted, but the Jewish side of my family is extremely important to me and highly influential in my life. I’ve seen several people asking a similar question but no one has really been able to answer with my details. Here is the necklace I have ordered; https://www.etsy.com/listing/579014913/star-of-david-with-cross-necklace-cross?ref=yr_purchases
Thank you!

Comment: It's forbidden for a Jew to wear a cross

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I have edited your question to depersonalize it - personal questions are most likely to be closed

Comment: Bear in mind that tens of thousands of our ancestors chose to die rather than join Christianity.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is fair to say many Jews would find it distasteful or offensive (I certainly would). The cross has been used as a symbol in Jewish massacres for centuries (e.g., during the [Crusades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusades)). Beyond that, wearing both symbols together appears to equate both religions even though their belief systems are fundamentally opposed.

Whether it is permitted by Jewish law might be a matter of dispute. R Ari Enkin brings an opinion forbidding it ([here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2018/12/non-jewish-religious-symbols/))

> R Menashe Klein was once asked by a doctor if he could wear his
> hospital-issued coat which includes a cross as part of the hospital’s
> logo on the front of the coat. He responded that the permissibility of
> wearing such a coat depended on the purpose of the image of the cross.
> **If it has religious significance, then it would be forbidden.**

There appear to be other perspectives brought in this [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28983/11501).