# On the design of the current universe -- why did G-d let there be suffering in the world

Tags: creation

**PREAMBLE: I'm processing (thinking about) all the comments and will try to update the question shortly. Thanks.**

A few weeks ago I was having a debate with born-again Christians (they were trying to convert me -- I'm not Jewish and am an atheist) and I put a question to them which I've often used in other similar situations and is one that is of genuine interest to me: why did G-d (for those who think he/she exists) design the current Universe the way he did -- given that there is so much suffering in the world?

The example I often use is one that is very disturbing to me: when the Nazi Dr. Josef Mengele was conducting experiments on human children by boiling them alive -- why didn't G-d immediately intervene? If I understand the faculties ascribed to G-d according to most religions, he/she has infinite power, wisdom, transcends time. Why did he not design a universe that for example had protection systems for the weak. Like in science fiction movies a force field would protect the weak from the tormentor. I'm using this phrasing to conduct a though experiment -- an alternate design could have been where there was no human suffering.

So the question: does Judaism address this question of human suffering? Would appreciate it if I could get some insights that can be understood by a layman like me.

Thanks.

Notes:

1. I realize that this may be related to the question on why G-d allows evil to exist like the one asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/why-does-evil-exist) -- but here is how mu question is different. One can suffer even in the absence of evil -- like say being burned in a car crash. On the the other hand a universe with safety mechanisms would prevent suffering even if evil existed.
2. Regarding the note that: it's really G-d's choice how he/she wishes to design the universe -- I would again assume that G-d, one who has compassion and love would not choose a Universe with suffering -- I mean I'm a mere defective mortal and given the choice, even I would not choose a Universe with suffering
3. On the note that it is irrelevant to those who suffer regarding what type of a universe they would prefer to live in (since they are not G-d) -- my submission would be that ethically (at least according to human ethics) the affectee, especially someone who is the lesser power-wise should have a say, especially since the suffer never really asked to be created or was given a choice in that matter and he/she has a frail existence vis-a-vis someone like G-d. So IMHO, yes they should have a say in the design of the Universe if they are going to be at the receiving end of suffering

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8855/why-did-g-d-not-stop-the-holocaust/8877#8877

Comment: (in fact, probably a dupe - the answers there seem to address this as well...)

Comment: Most of the answers point out that it would obviate free will, including your free will to make the atheist mistake.

Comment: @sabbahillel -- yes I've heard that -- but to me that's like saying that the limitation imposed by gravity obviate free will. I would still be free to explore physical sciences, ethics, etc.

Comment: @sabbahillel -- but I would be interested in how safety mechanisms that prevent a 6 year old girl from being boiled by Mengele would prevent me from choosing to be an Athiest. An explanation that used something akin to Einstein gedanken experiment would be sublime. cheers!

Comment: @user1172468 There is a quote I can't find it now from the Talmud that someone only dies when all those that are affected by it (suffer from him dieing) deserve it. Children under 13/12 years old die for the sins of there parents (maybe you can say they gain from it). How can you take as an axiom that suffering is bad, there are a lot of examples how suffering is for the good. (Suffering is in the head) read the book Man's Search for Meaning.

Comment: @user1172468 Since choosing to be an atheist is on the same order as believing than "Can G0d create a 4 sided triangle" is a valid question, it appears obvious to me that the "safety mechanism" would have to be an obvious miracle that could not be explained "naturally". However, one question would be at what age would you end the "safety mechanism" that you are asking about? What would happen after that "safety mechanism" ends? What would be the nature of such a "law of nature"? If a forest fire starts, how would you cause it to avoid all people?

Comment: @user1172468 Since the "laws of nature" appear to work on everyone at every time, you are able to pretend that there is no G0d. However, if a child falling off a cliff gets picked up and put back on top, while a deliberate suicide is allowed to fall I do not see how there can be "laws of physics".

Comment: @sabbahillel, many thanks for the note -- I'll update my question once I've had sometime to think about it -- but I think it could be a new kind of science: the laws of safety?, just as we have the laws of physics, time, etc. -- that is at least one way which it could be made to work -- there could be other ways. For example the Laws of physics do not have to be mathematical -- again we are taking about a G-d here, who I take is expected to be a great engineer.

Comment: @user1172468 Among other things, consider the discussions of Joseph being put into the pit by his brothers. Part of the discussion involves Hashem stopping the snakes and scorpions from biting or stinging Joseph (like Daniel in the lions' den), but not being "able" to stop the brothers if they had decided to murder him. This is a complex issue and may have answers elsewhere.

Comment: many think @sabbahillel -- good point

Answer (score 3):

Before one can understand why the world is the way it is, he must first understand what is its purpose.

[Ramchal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Luzzatto) and others teach that the purpose of this world is to act as an environment where human free will can function. (see Derech Hashem ch.2 and many other places).

This is why every phenomena has room for an atheistic explanation. God created life forms in a seeming common ancestry, the world appears like a cosmological accident, the cruelty of animals in nature, etc.

It is all necessary for the purpose of making room for free will and the requisite amount of it.

Once you understand this, then the problem of evil is not such a difficult question. We cannot understand all the details as God said to Job but we have a framework for understanding its necessity. Eventually all accounts will be balanced out.

This is discussed in more detail in [a lecture](http://dafyomireview.com/audio/RSimcha_Wasserman-Man_in_Fleeting_World.mp3) by Rabbi Simcha Wasserman, one of the great Torah sages of our times.

Comment: I couldn't find a bio of RSW to include. Surprising if he is one of the greatest Torah sages of our time.

Comment: the internet is not a good measure. some background here http://articles.latimes.com/1992-11-05/news/we-1397_1_rabbi-simcha-wasserman